# RSpec, FactoryGirl and ActiveRecord testing without rails

Tags: rubygems, rspec2, factory-bot

I'm building an independent gem you can look at the source code here:
https://github.com/mabounassif/facebook_event_fetcher.git

With my current setup, I can't test using FactoryGirl without setting up a test database first. What is the correct way to 'prepare' my test database?

The solution I had in mind was to create a db:test:prepare rake task. Basically, it deletes the test.sqlite3 file if present and then creates a new file and migrates the database with the correct table setup.
It seemed to be a clean solution at first, but I got the ActiveRecord NotConnected when I ran the rake task, and it seemed messy to me to have to setup the connection inside the Rakefile, especially that I've done that in the spec_helper.rb. It seems repetitive and unclean.

Can anyone hint on how I should proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally opted for setting the ActiveRecord connection again in the Rakefile.
That's my final setup, might come in handy for someone out there:

https://github.com/mabounassif/facebook_event_fetcher

The juicy part of it all is the rake file:

```
namespace :db do
  desc "Migrate the database through scripts in lib/generators/facebook_event_fetcher/install/templates. Target specific version with VERSION=x"
  task :prepare => :environment do
    ActiveRecord::Migration.verbose = true
    ActiveRecord::Migrator.migrate('lib/generators/facebook_event_fetcher/install/templates', nil)
  end

  task :environment do
    File.delete('db/test.sqlite3') if File.exist?('db/test.sqlite3')
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(YAML.load_file("config/database.yml"))
    ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(File.open('db/database.log', 'a')) 
  end
end
```